# Derived category of local systems of finite type on a $K(\pi,1)$ space: an explicit counterexample

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

Let $X$ be a nice enough topological space. I am mostly interested in smooth complex algebraic varieties. One may ask whether the bounded derived category of the category $\mathrm{Loc}(X)$ of local systems of finite type coincides with the subcategory $D^\mathrm{b}_{\mathrm{Loc}}(X)$ of objects of the derived category of sheaves with cohomology sheaves which are local systems of finite type.

This has [already been discussed on this site](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/360726/is-the-derived-category-of-local-systems-equivalent-to-the-derived-category-of-s), and the consensus is that the answer is positive if we drop the finite type condition and if $X$ has trivial higher homotopy groups, but even for $X$ a $\mathrm{K}(\pi,1)$ space the question is very subtle with the finite type restriction in place.

But is there an explicit example of a space $X$ of type $\mathrm{K}(\pi,1)$ for which the functor $D^b\mathrm{Loc}(X)\to D^\mathrm{b}_{\mathrm{Loc}}(X)$ is not an equivalence?

Comment: Wait I'm confused, isn't it the opposite ? They agree when $X$ is a $K(\pi,1)$, and don't "essentially" as soon as $X$ has higher homotopy groups (that's not quite true but morally)

Comment: I think an infinite alternating group $A_{\infty}$ has no non-trivial finite dimensional representations but does have non-trivial group cohomology with coefficients in the trivial representation, so $\pi = A_{\infty}$ gives an explicit counterexample.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Could you elaborate on what you mean by "They"? If it's the derived category of local systems and the complexes with local system cohomology, then I agree with you. The point is that the argument breaks down if by local system you mean local system of finite type, and I am interested in an explicit example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can give an example that is even a smooth complex algebraic variety that shows up naturally in algebraic geometry.

Let $X$ be the moduli space of abelian varieties of genus $g>1$ with full level $3$ structure. (I could also use any other level structure that rigidifies it, or no level structure if I'm allowed to work with stacks).

The fundamental group of $X$ is a congruence subgroup of $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb Z)$. Any finite-dimensional representation of such a group factors through the product of its profinite completion and the algebraic group $Sp_{2g}$ by Margulis superrigidity (though I think this case was known before via the congruence subgroup property). In particular, the category of finite-dimensional representations is semisimple.

Hence the derived category of the category of local systems of finite type is simply the category of sums of shifts of local systems of finite type.

Thus it cannot equal the subcategory of the bounded derived category of local systems of finite type, since that category has nontrivial $\operatorname{Ext}$ groups arising from nontrivial cohomology classes.